# Send facebook notification from my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, notifications

How can I send facebook notification to my certain facebook friends from my iPhone app? Notification will be some text message.

PS: I have already done facebook integration and have stored their facebook ids.

Comment: Do you want to know about [app notification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) ?

Comment: It says: "Only apps on Facebook.com can use the App Notifications." but I would like to send from my iOS app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is restriction with the [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) at present which is noted in the documentation as :-

> Note: Only apps on Facebook.com can use the App Notifications. Also these notifications are only surfaced on desktop version of Facebook.com.

Instead you may like to use [App Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/) which may allow you the functionality which you are looking for, to send Facebook notification to your certain Facebook friends from your iPhone app.